# Client is not able to use Yum Server configured on Server under /home/RPMS file path

Tags: linux, yum, centos5, rpm

I have configured Yum Server on Server 10.0.0.1(Redhat 5.3)
All RPMS are here /home/RPMS/Server.

Now on another machine i have Centos 5.3 (10.0.0.30).I want to use yum Server of 10.0.0.1 on 10.0.0.3 as client.

So i did edit yum.conf file on client as

```
[b]
baseurl=ftp://10.0.0.1/home/RPMS/Server
gpgcheck=0
```

When i am passing command yum list then it is showing error.

```
[root@client30 ~]#  yum list
Repository 'b' is missing name in configuration, using id
ftp://10.0.0.1/home/RPMS/Server/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: [Errno ftp error] (113, 'No route to host')
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: b. Please verify its path and try again
[root@client30 ~]#
```

But if put RPMS on server under /var/ftp/pub/RPMS then ,evrything working fine.

I have already given 777 permission on server.

Kindly help what i can do so that client start using yum server configured on Server with the same file path.Actually size of / is small so i cant put files under /var/ftp/pub.

Kindly help

Comment: _When i am passing command yum list then it is showing error_ -> what errors?

Comment: The error is `[root@client30 ~]#  yum list
Repository 'b' is missing name in configuration, using id
ftp://10.0.0.1/home/RPMS/Server/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: [Errno ftp error] (113, 'No route to host')
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: b. Please verify its path and try again
[root@client30 ~]#`

Answer (score 1):

> Repository 'b' is missing name in configuration

Define a name for your repo, something like this:

```
[b]
name=Local repo - $basearch
baseurl=ftp://10.0.0.x/home/RPMS/Server
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

> ftp://10.0.0.x/home/RPMS/Server/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: [Errno ftp error] (113, 'No route to host')

It seems caused by a firewall. Can you access this URL via web browser?

Comment: `No route to host` from something I expected to be on the LAN generally indicated the host is down, rather than firewalled. But it could go either way.

Comment: Yaa u are right.Firewall was enabled sir.BUt i am able to ping.Now i disable firewall and selinux and again i tried then it is showing error

Comment: Now i disable firewall and selinux and again i tried then it is showing error  `[root@client30 ~]# yum list
ftp://10.0.0.1/home/RPMS/Server/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: [Errno f                                                                                        tp error] 550 Failed to change directory.
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Server.                                                                                         Please verify its path and try again

Comment: `ls -ld /home/RPMS/Server`?